# How to enable a prompt before deleting anything in Broadleaf administration panel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, broadleaf-commerce

is there any way out-of-the-box to set a prompt window or something like that before Deleting any content (for example products) in Broadleaf (4.0) administration panel? Right now when I click on Delete button it just deletes them without asking first. I found a javascript that might do it but before I try with it I wanted to be sure if there isn't any option like that in Broadleaf? The javascript I found is for a link and it is something like that:

```
<a class="confirm" href="/delete">Delete</a>
```

javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('.confirm').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")) {
            location.href = this.href;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you looking for the prompt("Insert whatever you want here"); function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option would be right before you delete it put in this code:

`confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?");`

Comment: @PiotrKukliński Yes, I mean the javascript option.